# How to find 10 most memory consuming processes using awk and top -b

Tags: bash, awk

I need to write a script that will show 10 most memory-consuming processes using awk and top -b command. I'd like results to be shown in two columns - in the first the name of process and in the second the amount of memory it is using. I've done some research but I couldn't find anything that would work for me. This is my first contact with programming ever and I have no idea how to start. Could anyone somehow help me? Every hint would be appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. You should add what did you tried. Please have a look to http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

```
top -ab -n1 | awk 'NR>17{exit} NR>7'
```

`top` options are:

- `-a`  - to sort be memory
- `-b`  - batch mode
- `-n1` - Make top stop after one iteration

Used `awk 'NR>17{exit} NR>7'` to make sure to print lines between 8 and 17 (first 7 lines being the summary of `top` command).

Comment: Thank you for your response, it works. However, results are shown in a bit different way than I'd like them to be. To show exactly what I mean, I found a code that works perfectly for me but it doesn't include top-b command.  Here it is:

ps axo rss,comm,pid \
| awk '{ proc_list[$2]++; proc_list[$2 "," 1] += $1; } \
END { for (proc in proc_list) { printf("%d\t%s\n", \
proc_list[proc "," 1],proc); }}' | sort -n | tail -n 10 | sort -rn \
| awk '{$1/=1024;printf "%.0fMB\t",$1}{print $2}'

Comment: This answer meets your requirements. Output is what top gives.

Comment: I forgot to say that I had to delete -a after top since I get "top: unknown option 'a'". Without it, the output is pretty different than I expected.

Comment: I just did. I didn't indeed explain what I wanted the output to be. Sorry for that.

Comment: Your edited question can be solved by `top -ab -n1 | awk 'NR>17{exit} NR>7 {print $NF, $6}'` But keep in mind `top` command varies a lot system to system.

Comment: Unfortunately, it didn't. I still get "top: unknown option 'a'". I guess it is because I use OpenSuse linux.

Answer (score 1):

And the answer is:

```
ps aux | sort -nk +4 | tail
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, but I need to use awk and top -b command. Unfortunately, my teacher requires it.

Comment: OP mentioned `bash` in tags, so his system is probably GNU, so `ps(1)` is from `procps-ng`, which can do sorting by itself: `$ ps auxk %mem | tail`.